# Autoload a simple DAO in Symfony2+Propel

Tags: php, symfony, propel, symfony-2.3

I've been working on a project and I decided it'd be a good idea to have some sort of, like, DAO, but simplified.

Basically, the only thing I want from it (right now, at least) is to fetch me objects by model name and id. I wrote this very simple piece of code:

```
class DAO {

  public static function get($className,$id) {
    $queryName = $className."Query";
    if (!class_exists($className) || !class_exists($queryName)) {
        return false;
    }       

    $q = $queryName::create()->filterByID($id)->find();
    return $q;

}

}
```

However, I found myself stuck with the implementation. I guess I need to somehow autoload it so that it'll be able to check for the existence of the classes and so that I could use it anywhere inside my app, but I don't know how. Can anyone help me out? Or if there's a better way to do that, I'll appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `Service`.

Definition from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html):

> Put simply, a Service is any PHP object that performs some sort of
>   "global" task. It's a purposefully-generic name used in computer
>   science to describe an object that's created for a specific purpose
>   (e.g. delivering emails). Each service is used throughout your
>   application whenever you need the specific functionality it provides.

Defining your class as a service is as simple as this:

**app/config/config.yml**

```
...
services:
    my_dao:
        class:        Your\Bundle\DAO
...
```

Now you can access `DAO` in your controllers doing something like this:

```
$dao = $this->get('my_dao');
```

When you make this call, the `Service Container` will create an instance of your class and return it. There will always be at most one instance (singleton) and if it's never called, it won't even be instantiated.

I recommend reading the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

### Opinion

It seems like you're having trouble adapting to the **Symfony way**.

If you take a look at [The Book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) you'll see that the `Entity Manager` in conjunction with your entity's `Repository` handle most of what `DAO`'s traditionally did. In other words, there's really no need for your `DAO` class.

For example, fetching any object by `id` is as easy as:

```
$om->getRepository('YourBundle:YourModel')->find($id);
```

Anyway, if you're particularly fond of that approach, you may want to try [this](https://github.com/fightmaster/dao) project.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not familiar with the symfony way :)